# Windows batch script to remove dashes from subfolders and the files within subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder full of subfolders with filenames which occasionally have dashes as the sixth character. These subfolders will contain files with finames which also have dashes as the sixth character. I need to remove all of those dashes in the filenames of both the subfolders and their files.

I have studied and modified some code for my purpose, but the script is changing the subfolder name first, which breaks the script as it attempts to change the filenames within the now-renamed subfolder.

Can someone point me in the direction of a solution?

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s ?????-*.*') do (
  set "old=%%F"
  set "new=%%~nF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!old!" "!new:-=!"
  endlocal
)
```

Comment: try excluding subfolders from the output of `dir` by adding `/A:-D` to the `dir` command

Comment: You should use `/A:D` for directories, there is no need to define a variable for `%%F`, as you can use that directly, and `%%~nF` should be `%%~nxF` as directories can include **`.`** characters.

Comment: @terror but then how does OP rename directories if excluded from the `dir` command?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current code is that the renaming of directories start from root, so if a rename was done, the next level folder / file is not found, because it's parent is now renamed an error. For that reason, run a `for` loop on the files first by excluding directories `/a-d` then use `for /D` instead with the `/R`ecursive switch to rename the folders:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /s "?????-*.*"') do call :process "%%~F"
for /D /R %%F in (?????-*.*) do call :process "%%~F"
goto :eof

:process
set "name=%~nx1"
ren "%~1" "%name:-=%"
```

**Result**

`dir`s and Files before:

[image]

and After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all of the replies. One thing that confuses me about this solution is it omits the disableDelayedExpansion which I have seen as necessary in all of the ren ... "%name:-=%" examples I've looked at.

Comment: `Delayedexpansion` is disabled by default unless you explicitly enabled it via `Setlocal` or via `cmd /V:ON` but that said, it is not needed at all. `EnableDelayedExpansion` is needed if you set and use variables inside of a code block,  like in your question code.